# What ScopeType should be used during construction of seam objects

Tags: seam

```
UserList userList = (UserList) Component.getInstance(UserList.class);
return userList.getUserByLoginId(loginId);
```

A sample code usage of fetching a user by login id is given below. I instantiate the UserList class to call the method. What ScopeType should I use here specifically so that the object's scope is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access authenticated users via your UserList object you must keep it in application scope. But, it is alive during the entire application life. So, it is not minimal.

Another approach may store logged-in users in a database table and you can query this table via an event scoped component. Event scope is equivalent of Http's "request" scope. So, it is killed after each server request.

Comment: The above code snipped is just illustrated as a sample. I have many such calls which needs to be made from various entity query classes to access various methods in them (ideally they are static methods) and all of these invocations happen within a method. Are you suggesting that I should deliberately use the Event scope while instantiating such objects or should I use the Method scope or something smaller?

Comment: You may use stateless (ScopeType.Stateless) components for this purpose.